# Angular5 Routing with navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm using Angular routing and I think I didn't use it in a proper way.

It works fine but it disturbed HTML navbars:- Info, Skills

On click of skills `<skills></skills>` should component popup as I used bootstrap modal for that (it was working fine before implementing routing).

and on click of Info, it should take me to

```
<div id="info">
```

Below is routing

```
const routes: Routes =[
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},          
        { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent}        
    ];
```

Below is HTML of the main page, its a header navbar, which should work properly whether it is in projects page or admin page

```
<ul class="navbar-nav  mr-auto navbarCustom">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="" href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
         <skills></skills>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/projects" href="#">Projects</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#info">Info</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It may be easier to show what you mean if you create a StackBlitz

Comment: What exactly isn't working at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `href` with routerLink.

Just Use `[routerLink]="''"` instead of `routerLink="" href="#"`.

and When you click on `Info`, it should take you to your `fragment (Your html id)`.
For Example in your case. 
It will be redirect you on URL like this :

`http://www....com/#/#info`. So `#hash-tag` with redirect to your fragment. because you are using `<div id="info">` in your html.

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsagmd) for angular routing.